# How to center a bold element?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Hy my example code:

```
Bold b = new Bold(new Run("TODO"));
b.FontSize = 50;
```

My Question is:

How to center the bold element?

Comment: What are you talking about? How is someone able to answer that question? What is Bold, what is Run? Is it Windows.Forms? Not very good question...

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is in reference to classes in System.Windows.Documents.  You need to set the TextAlignment property on the thing (a Paragraph usually) that b is contained in.

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph around the Run should define the alignment.

```
Bold b = new Bold(new Run("TODO"));
b.FontSize = 50;
var p = new Paragraph(b) {TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center};
```